# C# find text in a string then return the rest

Tags: c#, string, substring

I am trying to do something like this:

```
string foo = "Hello, this is a string";
//and then search for it. Kind of like this
string foo2 = foo.Substring(0,2);
//then return the rest. Like for example foo2 returns "He".
//I want it to return the rest "llo, this is a string"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Change it to `foo.Substring(2);`. Done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clarify the rule, what you want when for another string.

```
        string foo = "Hello, this is a string";
        int len1 = 2; // suppose this is your rule
        string foo2 = foo.Substring(0, len1);
        string foo3 = foo.Substring(len1, foo.Length - len1); //you want this?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = "Hello, this is a string";
Console.WriteLine(foo.Substring(0,2));
Console.WriteLine(foo.Substring(2));
```

Result:

```
//He
//llo, this is a string
```

If you need to do this all the time you could create an [Extension Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) and call it like so.

Extensions Method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Tuple<string, string> SplitString(this string str, int splitAt)
    {
        var lhs = str.Substring(0, splitAt);
        var rhs = str.Substring(splitAt);
        return Tuple.Create<string, string>(lhs, rhs);
    }   
}
```

Use Extension Method like so:

```
var result = foo.SplitString(2);
Console.WriteLine(result.Item1);
Console.WriteLine(result.Item2);
```

Result:

```
//He
//llo, this is a string
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this

```cs
public string FindAndReturnRest(string sourceStr, string strToFind)
{
    return sourceStr.Substring(sourceStr.IndexOf(strToFind) + strToFind.Length);
}
```

And then

```cs
string foo = "Hello, this is a string";
string rest = FindAndReturnRest(foo, "He");
```